# libreoffice/openoffice Auto Spell Check has never worked

Tags: spell-checking, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, hunspell

I have used OpenOffice/LibreOffice for at least a decade.    I do not write documents very often, and the biggest pet peeve I have is that I have to google the recipe to turn spell check on EVERY TIME I create a new document, because I just don't do it often enough to remember how.

The secret always is, but I always forget:

Tools > Language > For All Text > English (USA)

Once I do that, I start to see the red squiggly lines.

Is there a secret that will turn that on for me forever, so I do not have to google it everytime?

Thanx

Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this by saving a new template. Start by creating a new blank Writer document. Follow the same steps to change the language that you mentioned:

*Tools > Language > For All Text > English (USA)*

Next, save this blank file with the updated language as a template:

*File > Templates > Save As Template*

Provide the dialog with a suitable **Template Name** such as *Blank Page w Spellcheck*, select **My Templates** or other category and check **Set as default template**. Click **Save**.

To edit the template:

*File > Templates > Manage Templates* (Control-Shift-N)

Right-click on the template you created, and select **Edit**. Make your changes and save the .ott template file.